# How to use selenium-hudson plugins with my maven project‏

Tags: selenium, hudson, maven-3

I'm new here so i'm not sure if this the right place to ask my question
I use hudson with my maven3 (struts 2 web application) project and i installed all selenium
plugins on hudson (Grid, Hq...) but I don't know how to relate it with
my maven project . I did not find good tutorials about this points . So
any idea please ? (tutorials, ebooks..)
could you explain me how selenium tests my jsp pages where have i put this pages?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this takes some configuration.  Googling brings up [this one](http://blog.infostretch.com/integrating-selenium-tests-with-hudson-ci), which can possibly help you.

Comment: Thank's Raghuram it's really helpfull :)

Comment: Anything specific to maven? Article provided is for Ant and Selenium RC.